# ActionController::ParameterMissing in SubscribersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel like this is a straight forward issue, but no other solutions recommended seem to be working. Basically all I want is an app that creates a subscriber with the attribute phone number.

Subscriber Controller

```
    class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
      def index
      end

      def new
         @subscriber = Subscriber.new
      end


      def create
        @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
        @subscriber.save
      end

      def show
        @subscribers = Subscriber.all
      end

      def update
      end


      private
      def subscriber_params
        params.require(:subscriber).permit(:phone)
      end
    end
```

Create.html.erb

```
<div class="recent">
  <h3>Subscribe to Texts</h3>
  <%= form_for @subscriber do |f| %>
    <span><label for="phone">Phone</label></span>
    <%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <%end%>
</div>

<% [:success, :error].each do |key| %>
  <% if flash[key] %>
    <div class="<%= key %>" id="flash">
      <%= flash[key] %>
    </div>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If I take out .require(:subscriber) it will not save the subscriber and it will create a rollback transaction stating that subscriber is an unpermitted parameter

if I put subscriber under .permit it just won't save it through the form.

What do I do? I feel like this is straight forward which makes it all the more frusturating.

Edit: The program won't run with .require(:subscriber), if I put it under .permit(:subscriber, :phone) I get this in the server logs

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxx==", "subscriber"=>{"phone"=>"5555555555"}, "commit"=>"Create Subscriber"}
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :authenticity_token, :subscriber, :commit

If I just put .permit(:phone) I get the same thing

If I put @subscriber.save! in the create method I get this error:

```
app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:20:in `subscriber_params'
app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:6:in `create'
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2020-02-23 10:02:32 -0500
Processing by SubscribersController#create as HTML
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Phone can't be blank):

app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

Comment: So what is the issue exactly?  You want to save the record without having a `:subscriber` param?  It is a little unclear what issue you are having exactly.  What happens when you try to save the record with the code as is?  It might also help to post an example of the params that are getting sent over, we will likely need that to help you either way.

Comment: I want to create a new subscriber, if I issue the code as is it will give me the error ActionController::ParameterMissing in SubscribersController#create and not display the home page

Comment: Ok, can you post the params that are getting sent, you should be able to see them in the console when you submit the form

Comment: Yes, so to even run the program I need to take out .require(:subscriber) and then I'd get   Parameters: {"xxxx"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxx==", "subscriber"=>{"phone"=>"5555555555"}, "commit"=>"Create Subscriber"}
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :authenticity_token, :subscriber, :commit
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
If I put .permit(:subscriber, :phone), I get almost the same thing but with : "subscriber"=>{"phone"=>"8884848999"}

Comment: please post that in the question.

Comment: The issue is it is reading these as params getting sent `:utf8`, `:authenticity_token`, and `:commit`.  The others you want in there

Comment: what do yo umean by, "to run the program" you need to remove the `require`?  Are you saving this record with the code as is, or without the require, because that would cause it to want to read those params in.  What happens when you use the code exactly as you have it posted above?

Comment: Meaning, it won't even load the form if I have require, it'll say ActionController::ParameterMissing in SubscribersController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: subscriber

Comment: Right your controller is messed up.  You need a new action with `@subscriber = Subcriber.new` and that new action shows the form, the create method creates the record using a `post` when you hit save.  Your issue is you never have that new record to use

Comment: I created a new method, code listed above, and I get the same problem.

Comment: Your code is all out of line, you need to put the form inside the new view, not create, create, at least if you follow the rails convention, doesn't have a view file.  The form needs to go inside new (and is also typically rendered view include inside the edit view as well).

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: I posted an answer to help you finish this off, you will need to update your create method to save the record now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is out of line, at least in regards to the rails conventions.

Add a `new` method, which should be handling showing the form, not the `create` method.  Then move the form inside that and make sure to add

```
def new
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new
end
```

inside that new method, you need to create the record inside the create method.  You probably want something like this in there.

```
# POST /subscribers
# POST /subscribers.json
def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscribere_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @subscriber.save
      format.html { redirect_to @subscriber, notice: 'Subscriber was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @subscriber }
  else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @subscriber.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```